# problema con getchar en c

Tags: c

Hola gente tengo una pregunta. El codigo siguiente(incompleto) almacena los nombres de los estudiantes en <Estudiantes[MAX][40]> y despues con eso podria ver los nombres de todos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 30

void agregarEstudiantes(int n){
    int numero;

    printf("Cuantos estudiantes vas a agregar : ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    if((numero + n) > MAX){
        int numero = (MAX - n);
        printf("El maximo es 30.\nYa tenes %d estudiantes, no podes agregar mas de %d estudiantes.\n",n,numero);
    }else{

        for(int i = n+1; i < n + numero + 1; i++){
        printf("Nombre %d : ",i);
        fgets(Estudiantes[i],sizeof(Estudiantes[i]),stdin);
        strtok(Estudiantes[i], "\n");
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){ }
        }
    } 
}

int main(){

    printf("Bienvenido.\n\n");

    int numero = 0,num;
    do{

    printf("1 - Agregar estudiante.\n2 - Modificar estudiante.\n3 - Todos los estudiantes.\n4 - Vista individual.\n5 - Sacar estudiante.\n6 - Salir.\nRespuesta --> ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){ }

    switch(numero){
        case 1:
            num = numeroDevuelta();
            agregarEstudiantes(num);
            break;
        case 2:
            modificarEstudiantes();
            break;
        case 3:
            mostrarEstudiantes();
            break;
        case 4:
            vistaIndividual();
            break;
        case 5:
            sacarEstudiante();
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("Saliendo.\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Respuesta Equivocada.\n");

    }
    }while(numero != 6);

    return 0;
}
```

Mi problema aca, es que cuando quiero meter mas de 2 nombres en la opcion 1, siempre me pide que de un enter para poder meter el siguiente nombre. Creo que es un problema con el buffer o con getchar, pero la verdad no estaria entendiendo y probe bastantes cosas.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema se debe a la presencia del carácter de nueva línea `'\n'` en el `buffer`, lo que sucede es que se leerá de nuevo en la próxima llamada a `fgets`.

*Código actual*:

```
printf("Cuantos estudiantes vas a agregar : ");
   scanf("%d",&numero);
```

Una solución sencilla es agregar un espacio en el `scanf`.

*#1 solución :*

```
 scanf("%d ", &numero);  // espacio en blanco despuéss %d
```

Al implementar esta solución, cuando el `scanf` lea y descarte el carácter de nueva línea del buffer.

Otra posibilidad es limpiar el búfer después de los estudiantes y antes del loop:

*#2 solución :*

```
void agregarEstudiantes(int n) {
    int numero;

    printf("Cuantos estudiantes vas a agregar: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    if ((numero + n) > MAX) {
        int numero = (MAX - n);
        printf("El maximo es 30.\nYa tenes %d estudiantes, no podes agregar mas de %d estudiantes.\n", n, numero);
    } else {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}   // Borrar el buhfer
        

        for (int i = n + 1; i < n + numero + 1; i++) {
            printf("Nombre %d: ", i);
            fgets(Estudiantes[i], sizeof(Estudiantes[i]), stdin);
            strtok(Estudiantes[i], "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, perdon pero me podrias explicar porque si lo pones antes del for sirve y no adentro por favor? Porque cada vez que se ingresa un nombre por el fgets no quedaria el '\n' en el buffer? y si limpio afuera del buffer no quedaria mal despues? Perdon, es que me cuesta un poco entender el tema del buffer.  Gracias por la respuesta igualmente.

Comment: ¿Es esta la parte que quieres entender?   `else { int c;  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {} for (int...`

Comment: claro, la parte que quiero entender es porque se pone antes del for, y no adentro del for.

Comment: En la primera condición, verifica `if ((numero + n) > MAX)`. Si no se cumple esta condición, entra en el `else` que agregará los nombres de los estudiantes.

El scanf deja el `\n` en el buffer, con el while se leen los caracteres del buffer uno por uno hasta que encuentre el `\n` o el `EOF`, y se limpia el buffer antes de llamar a fgets... de esta manera siempre se asegura de que el búfer esté vacío y después de que se limpie, entra en el loop.